# $f_n\to f$ a.u. on $X$ iff there is $\{\varepsilon_n\}\downarrow 0$ s.t. $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\{|f_n-f|\geq\varepsilon_n\})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $f_n$, $f:(X,\mu)\to\mathbf{C}$ be measurable. We say $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a measurable $A\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(A)<\varepsilon$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $A^c$.

I want to prove or disaprove the following statement:

> Let $f_n$, $f:(X,\mu)\to\mathbf{C}$ be measurable. Then $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly on $X$ if and only if there is $\{\varepsilon_n\}\downarrow 0$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\{|f_n-f|\geq\varepsilon_n\})=0$

The if part is true: Assume there is $\{\varepsilon_n\}\downarrow 0$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\{|f_n-f|\geq\varepsilon_n\})=0$. Then given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $k_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\mu(B_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon,\quad B_\varepsilon=\bigcup_{n\geq k_\varepsilon}\left\{|f_n-f|\geq \varepsilon_n\right\}.
$$
Then $|f_n-f|<\varepsilon_n$ on $B_\varepsilon^c$ for all $n\geq k_\varepsilon$. Let $n\to\infty$ to see that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $B_\varepsilon^c$.

However, I don't know how to prove the only if part, and can't find a counterexample either.

Comment: I think this might answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2714634/1104384

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That question suggests that the only if part is false, but I still need a counterexample to prove this.

Comment: The "only if" part of the linked post should be equivalent to saying that there exists a decreasing sequence $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ tending to $0$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\bigcup_{n\geq k}\{|f_n-f|\geq\varepsilon_k\})=0$, and so it could just be a typo (with $n$ instead of $k$) in the problem that was given to you or something like that, I don't know. Or maybe it is equivalent after all?